# ajax response posts a dict correctly but can't get to print it out

Tags: javascript, json, django

I am trying to print out the response to an ajax request. I am getting a "undefined" when (down there) I write ${obj[property][0]}  it follows the index to 1, 2 etc

I can see both in the console and by alert-ing the response (data) that it does send the correct data  in the form of a dictionary although it surely is json because that is what I send as response (and that is what web tools shows). However if I alert-out the "obj" I get "object" but can't see real values I get this: [object Object]

This is the ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  // open document ready
    $('.botontest').on('click',function(){  // opening click function
        var value = $(this).val()
        alert(value);
        $.ajax({  // opening ajax obviously
        url:"{% url 'bill' %}",
        type:'POST',
        data:{'name':value, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}'},// closes data field
        datatype:'json'
            }).done(function(data) {
    
    obj = JSON.parse( data);


    alert(data); // it prints me all data alright in the "alert" box


  // I leave out the headers.

    for (const property in obj) {

      tableHTML += "<tr><td>"
      tableHTML += `${property}</td>  <td>${obj[property][0]}</td><td>${obj[property][1]}</td>\
      <td>${obj[property][2]}</td><td>${obj[property][3]}</td><td>${obj[property][4]}</td><td>${obj[property][5]}</td>\
      <td>${obj[property][6]}</td><td>${obj[property][7]}`
      tableHTML += "</td></tr>"
    }

    tableHTML += "</tbody></table>"
    //place the tableHTML in the document
    $("#respuesta").html(tableHTML);
        });  // closing ajax group
            console.log(value);
    }); // closing the click function

});// closing document ready
 </script>
```

My response from Django is:

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(datax, default=str))
```

what baffles me is that I copied pasted that code from other project of mine and there it worked fine.
[screenshot from firefox webtools of what is posted as response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3Iab.png)

EDIT:

```
They want to see the response from django. There it goes 

datax = {'last_ht_water':last_hot_water,
                                                      'last_cold_water':last_cold_water,
                                                      'last_but_one_hot_water':last_but_one_hot_water,
                                                      'last_but_one_cold_water':last_but_one_cold_water}

return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(datax, default=str))
```

Comment: You need to include the actual response being returned by Django.

Comment: It is a dictionary, I pasted part of it in the question

Comment: Each one of those properties is not an array and yet you try to access it using [index]

Comment: That is quite evidently NOT the response you got from Django.  What you have posted contains JavaScript variable names, which Django would not return.  You need to post the actual raw data of the response being retuned.  Use your browser tools and examine the response body or just use something like postman or curl to get the raw response.

Comment: replace `alert(data);` with `console.log(data)` - refresh, rerun, hit F-12 and copy+paste in the original question.. but my assumption is you just need to do `data['last_ht_water']`

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was to place square brackets around the values, so that the response is an array. That way, the javascript code on the receiving end prints it correctly.

Comment: Better to show the change yiu made in code.